# Fastest way to know if a BrokeredMessage from Topic will be received by a subscription receiver

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I work with azure Topics/Subscriptions for a project.
And i want to find the fastest solution to know if a BrokeredMessage will be received by 1 subscription at least.

I found a basic solution :
Before to send the message, i call GetRules method to iterate throught sql filters :

```
var rules = NamespaceMgr.GetRules("topict1", s.Name);
foreach (var ruleDescription in rules)
{
     Console.Write(ruleDescription.Name);
     var filter = ruleDescription.Filter as SqlFilter;
     if(filter != null)
     {
          expressions.Add(filter.SqlExpression);
     }
     //...examine exisitngs expressions to know if the message will be handled by a subscription receiver
}
```

Is there a faster way ?

For example, is there a way to send the message instataneously the message in another queue if he didn't find a receiver to go ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is wrong. Topics are created to decouple publishers and subscribers. Your publisher should **not** be concerned about the fact if subscribers exist or not. Events are broadcasted, so if no listeners are found, those messages go nowhere.

There's a setting topic setting, [`TopicDescription.EnableFilteringMessagesBeforePublishing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.topicdescription.enablefilteringmessagesbeforepublishing) that when is set to `true` will throw `NoMatchingSubscriptionException` exception where there are no subscriptions that would be able to process a message. It is **not** intended for production.

Comment: Is there a similar way for the production ?

Comment: It works anywhere. Just not recommend for production.